# How to share functions in Coffeescript? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, coffeescript

I have one function that should be used in two different events, but I can't make it work. Where am I making a mistake? Or do I have to use Class instead?

```
coment_error = (that) ->
  $this = $(that)
  $new_answer = $this.parent('.new_answer')

  $new_answer.on('ajax:success',((evt, data, status, xhr)->
    $new_answer.hide()
    $('.open').show()
  ))

  $new_answer.on('ajax:error',((evt, data, status, xhr)->
    $(this).addClass("error")

    ))

$(document).on("click", ".new_answer > INPUT[type='submit']", coment_error($(this)))
$(document).on("click", ".new_comment > INPUT[type='submit']", coment_error($(this)))
```

Comment: Can you please post also your HTML because from that snippet of code alone it's hard to tell what's not working. Are you sure your jquery selectors are correct?

Comment: thx for correction..., davidfurber gave me right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the last two lines execute the function immediately instead of when the events are called.

```
$(document).on("click", ".new_answer > INPUT[type='submit']", coment_error)
```

Also you don't want coment_error to receive "that" because "this" will automatically be bound to the clicked element. So you can get right down to $this = $(this).